# Datetime format in Global.asax

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, datetime

I am trying to change the datetime format from Global.asax and date format is changing perfectly but time format is not changing it remains 24 hrs i want in AM/PM.
Following is my code in Global.asax

```
protected void Application_BeginRequest(Object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        PEXIPOutlookPlugInsEntities1 db = new Models.PEXIPOutlookPlugInsEntities1();
        CultureInfo newCulture = (CultureInfo)System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture.Clone();
        newCulture.DateTimeFormat.ShortDatePattern = "MM/dd/yyyy";
        newCulture.DateTimeFormat.ShortTimePattern = "hh:mm tt";
        newCulture.DateTimeFormat.LongDatePattern = "MM/dd/yyyy";
        newCulture.DateTimeFormat.LongTimePattern = "hh:mm tt";
        newCulture.DateTimeFormat.DateSeparator = "/";
        Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = newCulture;
    }
```

What wrong i am doing.
Thanks

Comment: There's still another area needs covering: `Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture`. You'll probaly try setting on that.

Comment: Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = newCulture; I did this but still not working.